# Rendering partial with locals in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, partial-views

I am learning Haml.

My view files are like:

show.html.haml:

```
.content
  = render 'meeting_info', :locals => { :info => @info }
```

and _meeting_info.html.haml:

```
.detail
  %table
    %caption
      Meeting Informations of
      = info["meeting_name"]
...
```

When I tried running this I got an `undefined local variable or method 'info'` error.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this
**Without `:locals` and `:partial`**

```
.content
  = render 'meeting_info', :info => @info
```

No need to specify locals.

**With `:locals` and `:partial`**
You should specify locals in following case i.e specifying `:partial` for render

```
.content
  = render :partial => 'meeting_info', :locals => { :info => @info }
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just now i realized i have :locals but not :partials

Answer (score 15):

You would use the `:locals` option if you're calling render from a controller. When calling render from a view, you would simply do this:

```
= render 'meeting_info', :info => @info
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just now i realized i have :locals but not :partials