# Passing a local variable into a nested partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, partial-views

I have a page that renders a collection roughly like this:

index.html.haml

```
= render partial: 'cars_list', as: :this_car,  collection: @cars
```

_cars_list.html.haml

**Edit:** _cars_list has other info about the individual car.

```
%h3 Look at these Cars!
%ul
  %li Something about this car
  %li car.description
%div
  = render partial: 'calendars/calendar_stuff', locals: {car: this_car}
```

_calendar_stuff.html.haml

```
- if car.date == @date
  %div 
    = car.date
```

_cars_contoller.rb

```
def index
  @cars = Car.all
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
end
```

What happens in the calendar stuff partial is that `this_car` is always the first car in the cars collection, i.e. the same date gets printed over and over.

If I move the logic in `_calendar_stuff` into the `cars_list` partial, then the printed result changes as expected.

So it seems that Rails is not passing the local `this_car` object into the nested partial each time it renders the partial.

Does anyone know why?

P.S. If I structure the code with

```
@cars.each do |car|
  render 'cars_list', locals: {this_car: car}
end
```

I get the same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Try this refactoring and see if you get your desired output:

**index.html.haml**

```
= render 'cars_list', collection: @cars, date: @date
```

Get rid of the `partial` keyword, and pass in the `@date` instance variable as a local variable to encapsulate the logic in your partials.  This point I got from [Rails Best Practices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable).

**_cars_list.html.haml**

```
%h3 Look at these Cars!
%ul
  %li Something about this car
%div
  = render 'calendars/calendar_stuff', car: car, date: date
```

As you passed in `@cars` as a `collection`, this partial will have a reference to a singularized local variable called `car`, which can then be passed on to the next partial, along with the now-local `date` variable.  Since the partial being rendered is in a different location to here (over under `calendars/`), the `partial` keyword is explicitly needed here.

**_calendar_stuff.html.haml**

```
- if car.date == date
  %div 
    = car.date
```

**Edit**

Suggested to move the call to `collection` to **_cars_list.html.haml**, but that wasn't appropriate for the problem.

**Edit 2**

This is the version of the above code if you still wanted to specify the local variable as `this_car`, so you would be overriding the `car` local variable that `collection` would have generated automatically.

**index.html.haml**

```
= render 'cars_list', collection: @cars, as: :this_car, date: @date
```

**_cars_list.html.haml**

```
%h3 Look at these Cars!
%ul
  %li Something about this car
  %li this_car.description
%div
  = render 'calendars/calendar_stuff', this_car: this_car, date: date
```

**_calendar_stuff.html.haml**

```
- if this_car.date == date
  %div 
    = this_car.date
```

Comment: Tried it, but still have the same behavior.  A couple things:  1) the `partial:` is necessary in the `index.html.haml` file because i am using the collection: parameter also.  i believe you can only leave it off with something like `= render 'cars_list'`.  2) The singularized local variable car works great in the `cars_list.html.haml` file, but when i pass that into `_calendar_stuff` it always passes in the first `car` in the collection, not the current car in the iterator.

Comment: I've used `collection` without the `partial` keyword before, but if you're finding issues arise if you leave it out, by all means continue to use it.

Comment: I don't think that will work, as i want to render some code in `_cars_list` for each individual car and then render the `_calendar_stuff` for that same individual car.  I believe rendering `calendar_stuff` with a collection will render that partial one after the other for each item in the collection

Comment: Okay, fair enough, then the call to `collection` was originally in the right place. I might just remove that edit from my answer due to that.  I can't think then why only the first object in the list would be rendered unless `@cars` only contains one car.  I've got code very similar in one of my apps and rendering a partial-within-a-partial on a member object has worked without issue.

Comment: i'm an idiot.  The rails code was working perfectly, i had a js bug in the front end that made it appear that only the first item of the collection was being passed in.  thanks for your help, i'm going to just delete the question.

Comment: You probably don't need to go so far as to delete the question.  Lesson learned for anyone with the same issue is to double-check that their JavaScript code isn't interfering with anything.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti -- Your examples need to use 'locals' if you are using 'partial' -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5255921/704936